# Degree of determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I want to show that the determinant of the following matrix, $f(t)$, has a degree which is less or equal than $1$.

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
 c_1-t &   a-t &   a-t & ... &   a-t \\
   b-t & c_2-t &   a-t & ... &   a-t \\
   b-t &   b-t & c_3-t & ... &   a-t \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\     
   b-t &   b-t &   b-t & ... & c_n-t \\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

where $a,b,c_1,c_2, ... , c_n \in \mathbb{C} $

I've tried using induction on $n$ but this has led me nowhere. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Maybe start row-reducing first. Notice that row one minus row two will give you lots of zeros in the first row.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I have solved it now. If anyone wishes to see the solution just tell me to post it.

Answer (score 3):

The concrete way: Subtract row $1$ from all other rows.
This will eliminate $t$ from all other rows.
The claim now follows from symbolic determinant expansion along row $1$.

The general way: You could represent your Matrix as
$$\begin{align}
    M &= S - tuv^\top
&   u^\top = v^\top &= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}
\\  S &= ((s_{ij}))
&   s_{ij} &= \begin{cases}
        a   & \text{if $i<j$}
    \\  b   & \text{if $i>j$}
    \\  c_i & \text{if $i=j$}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}$$
and use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)
which gives
$$\det(M) = \det(S - tuv^\top) = \det(S) - t v^\top \operatorname{adj}(S)\,u$$
which proves your claim because $S,u,v$ are independent from $t$.
Note that this works regardless of the concrete values in $S,u,v$.
It suffices that $t$ brings at most a rank-one update to the matrix.